# Swift: extend a generic type where the associated type is Array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have a type `Container<T>`. I would like to add an extension where if `T` is an array, a function can be applied to each element of the array.

Something like:

```
class Container<T> {

    var item: T

    init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

extension Container where T: Array<Element> {

    func mapElements<U>(transform: (Element) -> U ) -> Container<[U]> {
        return Container(item.map(transform))
    }
}
```

The above code does not compile of course: `! Use of undeclared type Element`

Any ideas on if/how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Aha figured it out.

Instead of inheriting from `Array`, constrain `T` to inherit from `Sequence`. Then the following can be written:

```
extension Container where T: Sequence {

    func mapElements<U>(transform: (T.Element) -> U ) -> Container<[U]> {
        return Container(item.map(transform))
    }
}
```

Comment: great! but if I want use `index(of:object)` in the extension . it game me Value of type 'T' has no member 'index' . how can I fix it?

Comment: sequence doesn't have access to index, but if you change `Sequence` to `Array` it will give you access to that method.